# Are there any fees that must be payed to Ubuntu as an Source Code Management server?

Tags: server, license

I want to use Ubuntu (server) as our new source-code server (at the moment, we are using a Windows server) in the company where I work. Are there any costs (license fee, taxes, etc.) I have to pay for? The server would be only for internal use (git-server).

I read many things about Ubuntu/Linux and commercial use - but now i am very confused about that topic.

Comment: Related: [Can I legally use Ubuntu Server to create a commercial web application on Amazon EC2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62148/can-i-legally-use-ubuntu-server-to-create-a-commercial-web-application-on-amazon)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No.

The long answer. Ubuntu (server or desktop edition) itself can be downloaded for free (without costs) and you can use (and modify) it for free (without costs and freedom of speech). Theoretically speaking it could be possible that Ubuntu is going to ask money for Ubuntu, but that is highly unlikely, because I would host the source code in that case and you would be able to download the Ubuntu legally for free (without costs) from my website. This which I From the [about page](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) of Ubuntu:

> Ubuntu 'main' component licence policy
>
> All application software included in the Ubuntu main component:
>
> Must include source code. The main component has a strict and
> non-negotiable requirement that application software included in it
> must come with full source code. Must allow modification and
> distribution of modified copies under the same licence. Just having
> the source code does not convey the same freedom as having the right
> to change it. Without the ability to modify software, the Ubuntu
> community cannot support software, fix bugs, translate it, or improve
> it.

Git is [licenced](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/LGPL-2.1) under LGPL2 which contains this section:

> Our General Public Licenses are designed to make sure that you have
> the freedom to distribute copies of free software (and charge for this
> service if you wish); that you receive source code or can get it if
> you want it; that you can change the software and use pieces of it in
> new free programs; and that you are informed that you can do these
> things.

But you can [pay for support](http://www.ubuntu.com/management) if you want.

Comment: To add a short resume of this answer, Ubuntu is free for personal and commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

Summary:
Ubuntu (desktop and server) are free for private and commercial use.
An commercial support is optional (not free).

I should publish the code if I modify the source code of ubuntu.